# How to iterate through a linkedlist and return a value?

Tags: java

I am suppose to iterate thru a linkedlist and return the new balance in the linkedlist how do I do this? I've tried google and everything but I can't find anything. This is how far I have gotten

```
private LinkedList lista;
private int lopnummer;

public Register() {
    LinkedList lista = new LinkedList();    
    lopnummer = 0;

}
public int beraknaSaldo(){
    Kund k = new Kund();
    k.belopp = k.getBelopp();
    ListIterator listIterator = lista.listIterator();

    return k.belopp;
```

Comment: Use the *enhanced for* loop. BTW I tried to google as well. Predictably, it worked. http://crunchify.com/how-to-iterate-through-linkedlist-instance-in-java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple While loop will solve your issue.

```
LinkedList<String> lista = new LinkedList<String>();
//add Items to your linked list....
Iterator<String> itLista = lista.iterator();
while(itLista.hasNext()){
    String s = lista.next();
....//do what you will with the item in the list
}
```

You should also note the generics used

Always define what objects are in your Linked List. This will avoid errors with trying to cast the objects or getting an unexpected item.

**Edit for comment to add items to linked list**